# IN Clause issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one SQL output table like this

```
ITEM,LOC,PERIOD,QUANTITY
101,US,07/22/2015,500
101,US,07/02/2015,0
102,LON,07/22/2015,0
102,LON,07/02/2015,1000
```

But I want the output table as follows,

```
ITEM LOC 07/22/2015 07/02/2015
101  US   500             0
102  LON   0            1000
```

Please find the code which I have used below,

```
select * from
(
select item, loc, period, quantity
from example
)
pivot
(
sum (quantity) for period in ('22/JUL/2015','02/JUL/2015'));
```

If it is for 2 dates, then no issue in mentionning the 'IN' clause
If it is 1000 dates like weekly, monthly and daily. Then how ?

Below command is not working in 'IN' clause.

```
SELECT PERIOD FROM EXAMPLE WHERE PERIOD < TO_DATE(22/JUL/2015);
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why caps lock? It makes it so much harder to read.

Comment: `'22/JUL/2015'` is not a DATE, it is a string. `TO_DATE(22/JUL/2015)` relies on your local NLS settings, never rely on it, always use format model explicitly.

Comment: You cannot have subquery in IN clause. It should be [hard coded](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) values

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to use that date constraint. If I use Pivot xml, then the subquery is working and the output looks like                               ITEM,LOC,PERIOD_XML
101,US,<PivotSet><item><column name = "PERIOD">2015-07-02</column><column name = "AVAILABLE">0</column></item><item><column name = "PERIOD">2015-07-22</column><column name = "AVAILABLE">500</column></item></PivotSet>
102,LON,<PivotSet><item><column name = "PERIOD">2015-07-02</column><column name = "AVAILABLE">1000</column></item><item><column name = "PERIOD">2015-07-22</column><column name = "AVAILABLE">

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may be incompatible data types. If the period column on your table is DATE type, you are trying to compare strings/VARCHAR with DATE type.

If period column is a DATE try changing your `IN` to

```
SELECT period FROM example WHERE period < DATE '2015-07-22';
```

or

```
SELECT period FROM example WHERE period < TO_DATE('22/JUL/2015', 'DD/MON/YYYY');
```

Comment: While I execute the below                                                                           select * from
(
select item, loc, period, quantity
from example
)
pivot xml
(
sum (quantity) as available for period in (SELECT PERIOD FROM EXAMPLE WHERE PERIOD < '23-07-2015'));                                                  It shows not a valid month. Please help